# Can I use JSSC to communicate with usb devices

Tags: java, serial-port, usb

I need to communicate with a device with a rs232 out put,but my laptop doesn't
have a rs232 port,then i bought a rs232 to USB converter and now i want to listen on the
usb port for data,can i use jssc to achive this. ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is months old, but I see no answers.  The answer is yes.

You can test your cable by going to the JSSC google code project page and access the Wiki tab's JSSCTerminal link.  It's a Java Applet Terminal program that allows you to connect a device via your cable, set port, speed, stop bits, etc., and then send commands and receive data.

I am successfully using JSSC to write Java programs to download data from Blood Glucose Meters and GPS trackers to my Linux and Windows 7 desktops and my Windows 7 laptop.  My serial-to-USB cable uses an older Prolific chipset.  The FTDI chipset should work too.

Once the appropriate drivers are loaded in your OS the OS sees the connected cable as a COM port in Windows and usually as the serial device /dev/ttyUSB0 in Linux/Mac.  At this point you can use any Terminal/Comm program or library to interact with them including JSSC.  You can download and run the examples unchanged from the JSSC project.

Answer (score 1):

this lib is used by arduino ide on that purpose https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/arduino-core/src/processing/app/Serial.java